# raw_input in python, output wrong

Tags: python, raw-input

I am a freshman in python, and faced a problem of raw_input. see bellow

```
Welcome to the game, Hangman!
I am thinking of a word that is 1 letters long.
-------------
you have 8 guesses left.
Available letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
please give a guess letter: c
Good guess: c
-------------
Congratulations, you won!
None

*** ERROR: Failing test.
Expected line: Please guess a letter: c
Your code generated: please give a guess letter: c *** 

--------------------
```

this is the output, and my code to use the raw_input is

```
    guess = raw_input("please give a guess letter: ")
```

the right output is,

```
Welcome to the game Hangman!
I am thinking of a word that is 1 letters long
-----------
You have 8 guesses left
Available Letters: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Please guess a letter: c
Good guess: c
-----------
Congratulations, you won!
None
```

the difference is about the raw_input, could you explain what happened?

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578984-hangman/?in=user-4191373  Here is a Hangman that I made with Python3x. You can check this. The only difference is using `input` instead of `raw_input` because it's Python3x.

Comment: You are not showing the code which is failing but it simply seems to be expecting a different argument to `raw_input` ("guess a letter" pro "give a guess letter", proper-case "Please", etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the test script is expecting specific output of `Please guess a letter:`, your code has `please give a guess letter:`

If you change your `raw_input` prompt to match the text, the test will pass.